# PHP Session Data Not Being Stored simply

Tags: php, session

PHP Session Data are Stored once only, not able to update!

Please help me sessions are stored, but there's no way to update the session data:

Consider the following example code:

```
<?php

session_start();


header("Cache-control: private");


   $_SESSION['counter']++;

   echo $_SESSION['counter'];

   session_write_close();

?>
```

When called the first time the session file C:\Window\Temp\sess_fs3r6tfmoc2tpv9ggnv8542ib2 is generated containing the correct data:
`counter|i:1;`
and the session_cookie is also set, containing the same `sessionID:fs3r6tfmoc2tpv9ggnv8542ib2`

When I ran it again the counter does not increase! 
The file \Temp\sess_fs3r6tfmoc2tpv9ggnv8542ib2 is not getting updated.
The sessionID is correct however.

Please help, it seems to me a problem about the configuration.

```
I Use: 
PHP Version 5.3.10
Windows 7
Microsoft-IIS/7.5
with Zend Extension     220090626 

Session Setting were all default:
Session Support     enabled
Registered save handlers     files user
Registered serializer handlers     php php_binary wddx

Directive    Local Value    Master Value
session.auto_start    Off    Off
session.bug_compat_42    Off    Off
session.bug_compat_warn    Off    Off
session.cache_expire    180    180
session.cache_limiter    nocache    nocache
session.cookie_domain    no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly    Off    Off
session.cookie_lifetime    0    0
session.cookie_path    /    /
session.cookie_secure    Off    Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length    0    0
session.gc_divisor    1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime    1440    1440
session.gc_probability    1    1
session.hash_bits_per_character    5    5
session.hash_function    0    0
session.name    PHPSESSID    PHPSESSID
session.referer_check    no value    no value
session.save_handler    files    files
session.save_path    C:\Windows\Temp    C:\Windows\Temp
session.serialize_handler    php    php
session.use_cookies    On    On
session.use_only_cookies    On    On
session.use_trans_sid    0    0
```

Comment: Did you run it from a browser and not from the CLI? Sessions don't work from the CLI (at least, not simply). Also please verify that your browser accepts cookies.

Answer (score 2):

First user comment about session_write_close() @ http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php#107945

"Beware of session_write_close when calling PHP scripts from an Ajax page: this does not "finalize" the session data writing, but in fact it resets it!"

Just remove that line ;)

Comment: Thanks for helping. I removed that line. But it's still the same. The page request is also without ajax.

Comment: It's me again, i found the solution, so anyone who has the same problem:
It seems to me that IIS and PHP dont work together well.

I installed XAMPP for Windows -> XAMPP USB Lite.
Use C:\xampp for install.
Change Port in C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf from 80 to a free port like 8001.
Start: C:\xampp\apache_start.bat and C:\xampp\mysql_start.bat
Check your installation:
http://127.0.0.1:8001/xampp/index.php
PHPAdmin:
http://127.0.0.1:8001/phpmyadmin/index.php
Webroot is:
C:\xampp\htdocs